# MPI - One-sided communications

Tags: mpi

I'm trying to use one-sided communications in MPI.

The following example consists of an array of 4 doubles that is split between 2 processes.

The first process writes 0, 1, 2, 3 in the distributed array while the second one subsequently tries to read it. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I must be doing something wrong somewhere.

Thanks!

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  MPI_Init(0, nullptr);
  int rank, size;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  
  int n=2;

  double* data, x;
  MPI_Win window;
  MPI_Alloc_mem(n*sizeof(double), MPI_INFO_NULL, &data);
  MPI_Win_create(data, n*sizeof(float), sizeof(float), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &window);

  int i;
  
  MPI_Win_fence(0, window);
  
  if(rank==0){
    for(i=0; i<n*size; ++i){
      x=i;
      MPI_Put(&x, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i/n, i%n, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, window); 
    }
    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);
  }else{
    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);
    for(i=0; i<n*size; ++i){      
      MPI_Get(&x, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i/n, i%n, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, window);
      std::cout << i << " " << i/n << " " << i%n << " => " << x << "\n";
    }
  }
  
  MPI_Win_free(&window);
  MPI_Free_mem(data);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work how exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Only the last modified value is correct.

Comment: I have tried to replace the ```MPI_Win_fence(0, window);``` by adding instead ```MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_SHARED, rank, 0,window);``` and ```MPI_Win_unlock(rank, window);``` before and after the ```MPI_Put``` and ```MPI_Get```

Comment: An MPI program that calls `MPI_GET` in a loop with the same origin buffer and different target offsets is not a correct one since all MPI RMA calls are non-blocking. This means that `MPI_GET` only initiates the operation but there is absolutely no guarantee that the operation is complete until you call `MPI_WIN_FENCE`. You should make `x` an array and `MPI_GET` into different elements of that array, call `MPI_WIN_FENCE` and only then print the content.

Comment: Thank you very much! This piece of code was just an example to reproduce the problem but my code is afflicted in the same way. There are no loops but the buffer have a limited lifetime. Some redesign will be necessary. Thanks!

Comment: I think I have found what I needed. The problem is that I need random elements from a distributed array and this is done in functions that are exited while MPI_Put and and MPI_Get are, as you pointed out, asynchronous. The most simple solution would be to use MPI_RPut and MPI_RGet and make them blocking by waiting for the request.